# Google Chrome does not show response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I just noticed that the google chrome browsers developer console does not show any response from the server in some circumstances, while other browsers like firefox show it:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

I am just doing a normal ajax request:

```
    $("#logout").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: 'logout'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                window.location.replace('index.php');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Is this a bug or my fault?

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of the headers tab? Has a response actually been sent? Is there a header saying the response length is 0?

Comment: A request was definitely sent by the client, I will post a screenshot later.